# Can I use PortalSiteMapProvider in anything other than a SP application?

Tags: list

Could I leverage this in a console app, or a web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*PortlaSiteMapProvider* can be used in web service but not in console application. The reason is it will require *HttpContext* to initialize properly. *HttpContext* is null in console application.